# Two version on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Why the first code work, but the second code doesn't work?

First:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = Input::get('name');
$user->email = Input::get('email');
$user->password = Hash::make( Input::get('password') );
$user->save();
```

Second:

```
User::create(array(
    'name' => Input::get('name'),
    'email' => Input::get('email'),
    'password' => Hash::make( Input::get('password') ),
));
```

Error message:

```
Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `$fillable` variable on the model to let it know which fields can be **Mass Assigned**.

[Laravel Mass Assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment)

Update:

as **deczo** and **har2vey** have stated you can also use `$guarded` as a blacklist instead of `$fillable` as a whitelist.

Comment: `fillable` as whitelist or `guarded` as blacklist

Comment: my mouse messed up ... double clicked the upvote on your comment ... sorry was trying to up your comment  +1 to deczo

Answer (score 0):

For a simpler solution especially if you have no fields to guard, use $guarded instead:

```
//On top of your model class
protected $guarded = array();
```